# can we declare variables and use them in for loop in scala

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

Am trying to iterate for loop using already declared variables in scala but am getting the error "Not a valid block statement"

I had removed variable declaration line and its working fine.

```scala
 object FirstObject 
 {

    def main(args:Array[String])
    {

      var i:Int,j:Int; // variable declaration
      for(i <- 1 to 10; j <- 1 to 5)
      {
        println(s"($i, $j)")
      }
    }
 }
```

Expected result looks something like this

(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(1, 5)
(2, 1)
(2, 2)
(2, 3)
(2, 4)
(2, 5)
(3, 1).......

Comment: In this case it is not needed at all. Since the for will work without them. - Why exactly do you want to do this? - You can not have an unitialized variable in **Scala**, so you have to initialize them, you can use `_` to say you do not care about the value, but anyways the for will create a new variable `i` & `j` that shade the original. - BTW, this is not a for loop, **Scala** does not have for loops, this is called [`for comprehension`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html).

Answer (score 5):

You already answered your question to some extent, you don't need to initialize the variable externally, this is enough:

```scala
def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {
  for(i <- 1 to 10; j <- 1 to 5) {
    println(s"($i, $j)")
  }
}
```

This is a the  syntactic sugar for (not exactly to be precise):

```scala
Range(1, 11).foreach { i => // 1 to 10 produces Range(1, 11)
  Range(1, 6).foreach { j => // 1 to 5 produces Range(1, 6)
    println(s"($i, $j)")
  }
}
```

So the `i` and the `j` are the variable from the associated `foreach` in a nutshell.

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html) about it.

Comment: It's called *syntactic sugar*, and a `for` comprehension without `yield` desugars to `forEach`, not `map`.